# Using Graph to get a list of all my App IDs

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Does anybody know if it possible to pull a list of the IDs for all the apps that I own in Facebook?

I know that each app has its own ID in the Graph (an example is [here](https://graph.facebook.com/272106599479899)), but there doesn't appear to be connection between that and the ID of the Facebook user who created the app.

Basically, I need to script a management tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app profile pages should be visible at /me/accounts when you use an access token with manage_pages permission - i'm not aware of any other way to retrieve a list of apps you admin

Comment: Yip, that works. Not sure why I didn't see that before. I think I just browsed the first few entries and only saw Fan Pages. Thx.